# Angular5 with Bootstrap4 performance?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

I'm building an application with Angular5 and want to include bootstrap.
I included Bootstrap4 which (the JS part of bootstrap) has dependencies on `JQuery` and `Popper.js`.

I also read about using `CSS grid` for more flexibility than bootstrap as an alternative to bootstrap.

### Question:

Does using bootstrap significantly decrease performance (loading speed) because it has dependencies on `JQuery` and `Popper.js`?

Comment: man the css grid is just css code not depened on jquery and popper

Comment: Made the question a bit more clearer, I know that css grid is just css

Comment: You can create your webpage without Bootstrap. But what you'll gain in speed you'll loose in UX/UI.

Comment: bootstrap now is build with sass now u just can include the part u want like the grid only u don't have to include all bootstrap

Comment: Please, for the love of god. Don't use jQuery in combination with angular,  it makes 0 sense. Perhaps have a look into ng-bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other members mentioned, you can use bootstrap 4 without scripts.

Actually that for me seems the way to go, as bootstrap has specific angular packets that you can use (ng-bootstrap) to get the desired bootstrap features, like accordion, modals, datepicker etc.
Check them out: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

So jquery scripts, specially for angular, are obsolete.
Basic rule for any script should be: if you don't use it, don't include/load it. Much faster that way!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research about how to measure performance I found the following for anyone who is interested:

**Without JQuery/Popper.js and without bootstrap4:**

[image: bootstrap jquery performance]

**Without JQuery/Popper.js and with bootstrap4:**

[image: bootstrap jquery performance]

**With JQuery/Popper.js and with bootstrap4:**

[image: bootstrap jquery performance]

### Conclusion:

1. Adding bootstrap4 adds  ~150ms to load time
2. Adding bootstrap4 and JQuery+Popper.js ~25ms more

Comment: Are you loading them from your own server? Are all of them minified and gzipped? Also, loading via CDNs is probably a much better idea. Especially considering that most users will have those cached (soon) in their browsers and thus the load time is gonna be zero for all those files.